# How do I convince the Lean 4 type checker that addition is commutative?

Tags: lean, dependent-type, lean4, type-checking

In order to get acquainted with Lean and programming with dependent types I am trying to implement basic operations for a `Vector` datatype defined [following the example in TPiL](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/induction_and_recursion.html#dependent-pattern-matching) as:

```
inductive Vector (α : Type u) : Nat → Type u
  | nil  : Vector α 0
  | cons : α → {n : Nat} → Vector α n → Vector α (n+1)
```

I tried implementing an `append` function to concatenate two vectors as

```
def append : Vector α m → Vector α n → Vector α (m + n)
  | nil, v => v
  | cons h t, v => cons h (append t v)
```

but in the `nil` case I get the error

```
type mismatch
  v
has type
  Vector α n : Type ?u.1240
but is expected to have type
  Vector α (0 + n) : Type ?u.1240
```

The type checker apparently can't tell that `Vector α n` and `Vector α (0 + n)` are the same type. It works if I instead change the type of `append` to `Vector α m → Vector α n → Vector α (n + m)`, so that the expected type is `Vector α (n + 0)`. So apparently it can't tell that addition is commutative.

If I do change the type to `Vector α (n + m)`, then later when I use it to implement a function to reverse a vector it fails to type check again:

```
def reverse : {n : Nat} -> Vector α n → Vector α n
  | 0, nil => nil
  | n' + 1, cons h t => append (reverse t) (cons h nil)
```

The reason is that on the recursive call it expects `reverse t` to be of type `Vector α 1` and `cons h nil` to be of type `Vector α n'` (rather than the other way around) so that the result will have type `Vector α (n' + 1)` (rather than `Vector α (1 + n')`). So again the problem is that it doesn't realize that addition is commutative.

**What do I have to do to get the type checker to understand that `Vector α (m + n)` is the same as `Vector α (n + m)`?**

Comment: The type checker identifies `n+0` with `n` because its by definition of addition, whereas `0+n` does not reduce to `n`. The distinction is that the former equality is definitional, and the latter is semantic. The typechecker cannot decide equality of semantically equal terms, hence also why `n+m` cannot be identified with `m+n`.

Comment: @Couchy That makes sense, but it's possible to state and prove a theorem that `n+m = m+n`. Is there any way to use this proof to guide the type checker, for example?

Comment: I believe you can only prove that the two types are propositional equal. Given p of type $n + m = m + n$, the expression congr_arg (Vect \alpha) p will be a proof of that I believe. Unfortunately equality in type theory is more complicated than in informal mathematics.

Comment: @Merle I believe Lean 4 actually has definitional uniqueness of identity proofs (if `p : x = x` then `p = Eq.refl x`, definitionally), which sort of annihilates any complications to equality beyond "you have to be explicit about where you substitute equalities".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type theories typically have a two notions of equality. There is a "definitional" equality corresponding roughly to *syntactic* (so "external") equality modulo conversion rules (particularly beta-reduction). There is also a "propositional" equality represented by a type and terms inside the theory (the type family `=` in Lean). The propositional equality is "really" equality (e.g. you can prove `0 + n = n`), and the more restricted definitional equality is what the type checker uses when comparing "expected" and "actual" types (here, it can't show `0 + n` is definitionally equal to `0`, because the definition of `+` is such that `0 + n` does not reduce/simplify.)

Reflecting propositional equality to definitional equality (i.e. "convincing the type checker" of more equalities) is *not possible* in Lean, nor most theorem provers, since it makes type checking undecidable. Instead† you have the ability to "rewrite" or "substitute" according to a propositional equality: If you have proved `p : x = y` and you have `a : P x` then you can get `p ▸ a : P y`. That is, you explicitly take your term and "move it" along an equality. The type checker still considers `x` and `y` to be different, and `p ▸ a` is also different from `a` (unless `y` is definitionally `x` and `p` is definitionally `refl`, in which case `p ▸ a` is definitionally `a`).

Pulling lemmas for `0 + n = n` and `m + 1 + n = m + n + 1` from the standard library (that these are *nontrivial* is *why* the checker isn't trusted with handling them implicitly):

```
def append : {m : Nat} → Vector α m → Vector α n → Vector α (m + n)
  | 0, nil, ys => Eq.symm (Nat.zero_add n) ▸ ys -- I think ▸ is supposed to handle symming for you when necessary; not sure why it fails here...
  | m + 1, cons x xs, ys => Nat.succ_add m n ▸ cons x (append xs ys) -- outer goal Vector α (m + 1 + n), inner goal Vector α (m + n + 1)
```

Note that I have to add `m` to the matching in order to be able to pass it to one of the theorems.

†In actuality you usually have an induction principle for `=`, which is more general than just substitution. In Lean 4 `▸` is a (builtin) macro that uses this induction principle.

Comment: Thank you, this works and is exactly what I was looking for. The information I was missing was the existence of the rewrite operator.